# When is "事" used instead of こと for past experiences?

Tags: grammar, kanji, hiragana

In the "ことがあります" construction about past experiences, when is "事" used, and when is "こと" used?

The textbook used in class uses "こと":

> 六本木の おんせんに 行った ことがあります。

If it wanted to use "事" instead of "こと", it could have, as that kanji was taught in the same lesson. (Lesson 5 of "Japanese for Busy People II", revised 3rd edition)

However, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8B) says that the kanji form can be used, and "事があります" gets some hits in the Tanaka corpus on jisho.org

When is "事" used, and when is "こと" used?

Comment: In short, use 事 for "real" nouns and use こと for "dummy" nouns.  知っている事、三つの事、習い事 vs. 行ったことがある/ない、書くこと、ヘレンのこと

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe those two (ことがある and 事がある) are the same construction in terms of meaning and they only differ by the way こと is spelled.

こと used as a grammatical construction, like the one in the question, is more often spelled using hiragana in modern Japanese.

Comment: To give an equivalent English example: The pie that I ate. The word "that" there is used as a grammatical construction rather than to have the specific meaning of pointing at something in the world (e.g. look at that cat!)